# Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$. Show that $E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P[X>k]$

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$. Show that $E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P[X>k]$.

The question is taken from *Introduction to Probability Models, 10th Ed.* (Ross, pg. 91).

**Attempt.** Let $X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k$, with

\begin{equation}X_k=\begin{cases}1 & \text{when }X\leq k \\ 0 & \text{when }X>k\end{cases}\end{equation}

Since $E[X_k]=P[X\leq k]$,

$$E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty E[X_k]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P[X\leq k]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-P[X>k]\right)$$

And at this point I'm at a loss as to how I should obtain the result.

**Attempt 2.** Following drhab's help, I reformulated the definition of $X$ in terms of $X_k$. Using the same $X_k$ (for brevity of this post), let $X=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-X_k)$. Then

$$E[X]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty E[1-X_k]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(E[1]-E[X_k])=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1-P[X\leq k])=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P[X>k]$$

I believe this is correct now.

Comment: This is okay. Be aware though that you actually make use of the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem) combined with the linearity of expectation.

Comment: By the way, I would cite which edition of Ross you are using. In my edition (11th), the exercise is p. 85, exercise #46a.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/497101/15941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Do we really have $X=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k$?

If e.g. $X=3$ then $X_1=0=X_2$ and $X_k=1$ if $k\geq3$.

Comment: I'm trying to solve it now using $X=\sum(1-X_k)$. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You could also adapt the definition of $X_k$: $X_k=1$ if $X>k$ and $0$ otherwise. Then you have to start at $k=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Start with the definition:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum\limits_{\{x: p_x > 0\}}xp_x$$
where I use $p_x = \mathbb{P}(X = x)$.

Notice that:

$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}xp_x = 1p_1 + 2p_2 + \cdots + np_n\text{.}$$
Group these terms as follows:
$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}xp_x = 1(p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_n) + 1(p_2 + p_3 + \cdots + p_n) + 1(p_3 + \cdots + p_n)+ \cdots + p_n$$
resulting in 
$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}xp_x = 1(1-p_0)+1(1-p_0-p_1)+1(1-p_0 - p_1-p_2) + \cdots + 1(1-p_0 - \cdots - p_{n-1})\text{.}$$
What are those terms surrounded by $()$?

Now take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Is $X$ known to take on a finite set of values?

Comment: @DilipSarwate As long as the limit exists, take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: So why not include your comment in your answer?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Done. I wasn't sure how much detail to give since I meant it to be a hint.